# UIButton border cut when corner radius is given

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, rounded-corners

I have created the UIButton with specific position corner radius means left button have top left and bottom left corner radius and right button have top right and bottom right corner radius i have take the button in Xib and give border but i cut from some side i have attach the screenshot below.
[image]

Look at right side corner border cut. here is my code

```
  [btn_Newest setBackgroundColor:RGB(28.0, 91.0, 161.0, 1.0)];
    [btn_Newest.layer setBorderWidth:1.5];
    [btn_Newest.layer setBorderColor:RGB(28.0, 91.0, 161.0, 1.0).CGColor];
    [btn_Newest setClipsToBounds:YES];
    btn_Newest = (UIButton *)[self setroundCornersOnView:btn_Newest onTopLeft:YES topRight:NO bottomLeft:YES bottomRight:NO radius:7.0];


    [btn_Popular setBackgroundColor:viewTopBar.backgroundColor];
    [btn_Popular.layer setBorderWidth:1.5];
    [btn_Popular.layer setBorderColor:RGB(28.0, 91.0, 161.0, 1.0).CGColor];
    [btn_Popular setClipsToBounds:YES];
    btn_Popular = (UIButton *)[self setroundCornersOnView:btn_Popular onTopLeft:NO topRight:YES bottomLeft:NO bottomRight:YES radius:7.0];
```

**setroundCornersOnView** this function create specific side corner radius.Can any one help me in this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kindly try the following code. i think it will satisfy your requirements.

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:btnPush.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopRight | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(7.0, 7.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
maskLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;
btnPush.layer.mask = maskLayer;

CAShapeLayer *borderLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
borderLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
borderLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;
borderLayer.lineWidth   = 1.5f;
borderLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
borderLayer.fillColor   = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
[btnPush.layer addSublayer:borderLayer];
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting setroundCornersOnView .You can set cornerRadius to the button.
try below code.
`[btn_Newest.layer setCornerRadius:5];`

Comment: thanks for your replay but i have requirement that button should have look like screenshot. although i try with your answer.